# That's so meta!

Tags: code-golf, string

## Your Challenge

You must write a program/function etc. that takes a domain name of a StackExchange site and outputs the domain for the meta version of the site passed to it. Examples:

```
stackoverflow.com => meta.stackoverflow.com
codegolf.stackexchange.com => codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com
mathoverflow.net => meta.mathoverflow.net   
codereview.stackexchange.com => codereview.meta.stackexchange.com
```

Note: Subdomains are added to `meta.stackexchange.com`. Separate domains have `meta.` prepended. You don't need to worry about `stackexchange.com` or `meta.stackexchange.com` passed.

## Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Why post basically the same question within 10 mins? I know that ones a polyglot but is there really any purpose or difference from the other one?

Comment: It just seems to me as though its a rep grab.

Comment: Could you provide the specification rather than just saying it is defined by SE? Or a link to the logic used?

Comment: @JonathanAllan  Subdomains are added to `meta.stackexchange.com`. Separate domains have `meta.` prepended.

Comment: -1 for no specification.

Comment: I'm fairly sure there are exceptions not covered by the examples. E.g. isn't meta.stackexchange.com it's own meta site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Retina, 17

```
\w+\.\w+$
meta.$&
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfU64dowckVLhyU0sS9VTU/v8vLklMzs4vSy1Ky8kv10vOz@VKzk9JTc/PSdMDS6VWJGck5qWngqVyE0sy4GrzUkvAaotSyzJTyzFVAwA).

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Sed, 20

Score includes +1 for use of `-r`.

```
s/\w+\.\w+$/meta.&/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#Zco7DoAgEADR3nMYGyNciIbg8onAGtiAp3c1FDY208zjKlVflXgzywSkxSKZK2lzYINiI3ZhME0Gd3AYrRgLLuN1djBW0uQ/m4GGLdAC9L@@8aSAufJWHg).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/\w+\.\w+$/,'meta.$&')
```

```html
<input id=a oninput="b.innerText=a.value.replace(/\w+\.\w+$/,'meta.$&')"/>
<p id=b />
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
aR`\w+.\w+$``meta.&`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@58YlBBTrq0HxCoJCbmpJYl6agn///9Pzk9JTc/PSdMrLklMzk6tSM5IzEtP1UvOzwUA)

Matches the last two runs of word characters (separated by some other character), to which it prepends `meta.`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>57</s> 54 bytes

```python
l=input().split(".");l[:-2]+=["meta"];print".".join(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HcnBDoIwDADQu19hetpi7MEjhL/whhyWWaBa1mUU8e@n4V3fPrPQ@V42ah5VOk55M@dxzcLmAMG30jfX23DpeljIAgxtLpzsX/hSTk58rbBaiG/9UBlFd4y6wAmiPmlSGfFI@sY5pImO/AE)

Split on periods, insert `"meta"` before the second item from the end, join the list again on periods and print.

Answer (score 0):

## JS (ES6), 59 bytes

```
m="meta.",a=>a.split(".").length-2?a.replace(/\./,"."+m):m+a
```

If the string passed to the function expression has more than 1 `.` in it, a `.meta.` is inserted in the first `.`. Otherwise, `meta.` is appended to that string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
ṣ”.ṙ-2;“£2v»W¤ṙ2j”.
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w5@JHDXP1Hu6cqWtk/ahhzqHFRmWHdocfWgIUMcoCSf3//z85PyU1PT8nTa@4JDE5O7UiOSMxLz1VLzk/FwA)**

#### How?

```
ṣ”.ṙ-2;“£2v»W¤ṙ2j”. - Main link: domain string
ṣ”.                 - split at occurrences of '.'
   ṙ-2              - rotate right by -2
             ¤      - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad
       “£2v»        -     dictionary lookup of "meta"
            W       -     wrap in a list
      ;             - concatenate
              r2    - rotate right by 2
                j”. - join with '.'s
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 48 Bytes

```
echo preg_filter("#\w+\.\w+$#","meta.$0",$argn);
```

but we should better do it like this

```
echo strstr($argn,"meta.")?$argn:preg_filter("#\w+\.\w+$#","meta.$0",$argn);
```